# Realm Browser ask for encrypted key after update to Xcode 8.3

Tags: ios, xcode, encryption, realm

I'm using Realm as database in an app. Until I've updated Xcode to 8.3 version, I was able to use Realm Browser to read realm file directly from simulator (I didn't set any encryption key on Realm configuration).

But, since yesterday, when I upgraded Xcode, Realm Browser asks for an encryption key. I've open older realm files from the same project, but no those new database files created on run with Xcode 8.3.

Any idea about what is happening? Maybe something related whit the new filesystem used by Apple?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realm 2.5 introduces new file format. Existing files will automatically be upgraded when they are opened. The Realm browser in AppStore doesn't support the new file format. You can use new version of browser that can be downloaded from GitHub until new version will be passed AppStore review.

https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/releases/tag/v2.1.7